# Saving data in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

How do I save a data to MongoDB? I have a about 1GB size object turned to BsonDocument. I want to save this file to MongoDB. Since the mongo supports only 4MB, how I would I save this gigantic bsondocument? If I use gridFS, would the gridfs automatically chunk this large object by itself and send it to the server?

Please any help and pointers are appreciated.

Is there any tricks and stuff that I should know about. I'm not saving any images, videos or audios. I'm saving a object graph (2GB) Do I have to turn the object graph to bsondocument and then send it to the server?

Comment: Might help: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb

Comment: MongoDB documentation is in bad state.

Comment: One small correction, unrelated to solving the issue as a whole, the max document size in MongoDB now is 16MB, not 4MB as stated.  Not meaning to be a pedant, I just have an urge to correct it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GridFS will basically make this object into a series of "file chunks" and it will behave like a file.

> I have a about 1GB size object turned to BsonDocument.

You need to break this out into multiple BsonDocuments against which you can query. MongoDB is completely incapable of handling a single giant BsonDocument.

MongoDB is intended to store lots of little BsonDocuments and allow you query against them.

> I'm saving a object graph (2GB)

Is it possible to break this out into queryable pieces?

If not, then you may be using the wrong DB. There are a few Graph Database designed for this type of storage and querying. Check out [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) or Microsoft's [Trinity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trinity/).

These are Graph DBs designed for handling this type of work.

Comment: I'm going with SQL Server. Migrating everything to database and entity data model. sql is the most reliable and scalable solution. I might have 1TB of data in the future.